# Need an explanation for how this specific recursion works

Tags: c, recursion, printf, function-definition

I am currently learning recursion in c language. I encountered this when trying out some stuff

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw(int x) 
{
  if (x > 0) 
  {
    draw(x-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    {
      printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main (void) 
{
   draw(4);
}
```

I expected the code to print:

```
****
***
**
*
```

Instead, it prints:

```
*
**
***
****
```

Can anyone please explain why this is the case?
Thank you.

Comment: Debug it: you'll learn how a debugger and recursion work.

Comment: A piece of paper and a pencil are most helpful here.

Comment: re "paper and pencil" see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11666815/849891), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285838/849891).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on *when* recursion occurs!

What happens in this code example is that the recursive call is done *before* you actually print a line:

```
draw(3)
    -> draw(2)
        -> draw(1)
            -> draw(0) // not doing anything
            -> print one asterisk
        -> print two asterisks
    -> print 3 asterisks
```

If you, in contrast, print first the asterisks and then call recursively:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
{
    printf("*");
}
printf("\n");

draw(x-1); // note: moved behind printing
```

*then* you get the result you originally expected.

Side note: `printf("x")` with just a single character contained in the string is pretty inefficient compared to using `putchar('x')` which effectively does the same (though admitted, you won't be noticing on running your programme).

Answer (score 2):

It helps if you expand each call in-line:

```
// draw(4) ==
{
  // draw(3) ==
  {
    // draw(2) ==
    {
      // draw(1) ==
      {
        // draw(0) ==
        { no-op } ;
        print 1 '*' ;
      } ;
      print 2 '*' ;
    } ;
    print 3 '*' ;
  } ;
  print 4 '*' ;
}
```

`draw(4)` first calls `draw(3)` and ***then*** it prints 4 `'*'`s.

But what does `draw(3)` do? It calls `draw(2)` and ***then*** it prints 3 `'*'`s and so on. So 3 `'*'`s are printed before 4 `'*'`s, and 2 `'*'`s are printed before 3 `'*'`s, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In each call of the function it at first calls itself with the decreased by one value of `x` (provided that `x` is greater than `0`)

```
void draw(int x) 
{
  if (x > 0) 
  {
    draw(x-1);
    //...
```

and only after that outputs the symbol `'*'` `x` times.

If you want to get the expected result then the function shall at first output the symbol `'*'` `x` times and after that call itself with the decreased by one value of `x` as for example

```
void draw(int x) 
{
  if (x > 0) 
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    {
      printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");

    draw(x-1);
  }
}
```